# Ubuntu VM "read only file system" fix?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, filesystems

I was going to install VMWare tools on an Ubuntu server Virtual Machine, but I ran into the issue of not being able to create a cdrom directory in the /mnt directory. I then tested to see if it was just a permissions issue, but I couldn't even create a folder in the home directory. It continues to state that it is a read only file system. I know a little about Linux, and I'm not comfortable with it yet. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Requested Information from a comment:

> *username@servername*:~$ mount 
>  /dev/sda1 on / type ext4
>   (rw,errors=remount-ro) 
> proc on /proc
>   type proc (rw) 
> none on /sys type sysfs
>   (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) 
> none on
>   /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl
>   (rw) 
> none on /sys/kernel/debug type
>   debugfs (rw) 
> none on
>   /sys/kernel/security type securityfs
>   (rw) 
> udev on /dev type tmpfs
>   (rw,mode=0755) 
> none on /dev/pts type
>   devpts
>   (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
>   
> none on /dev/shm type tmpfs
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev) 
> none on /var/run
>   type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755) 
> none
>   on /var/lock type tmpfs
>   (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) 
> none on
>   /lib/init/rw type tmpfs
>   (rw,nosuid,mode=0755) binfmt_misc on
>   /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type
>   binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)

For sure root output.

> root@server01:~# mount 
> /dev/sda1 on /
>   type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro) 
> proc
>   on /proc type proc (rw) 
> none on /sys
>   type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
>   
> none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type
>   fusectl (rw) 
> none on /sys/kernel/debug
>   type debugfs (rw) 
> none on
>   /sys/kernel/security type securityfs
>   (rw) 
> udev on /dev type tmpfs
>   (rw,mode=0755) 
> none on /dev/pts type
>   devpts
>   (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
>   
> none on /dev/shm type tmpfs
>   (rw,nosuid,nodev) 
> none on /var/run
>   type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755) 
> none
>   on /var/lock type tmpfs
>   (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev) 
> none on
>   /lib/init/rw type tmpfs
>   (rw,nosuid,mode=0755) binfmt_misc on
>   /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type
>   binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please print the output of the "mount" command ? (no parameters needed)

Comment: Added to the answer. Thanks for asking for helpful information.

Comment: Just to be sure: "sudo mkdir /mnt/cdrom" fails, right?

Comment: What confuses me is that it says it's a read only file system. The output of the command states "rw" which is read write filesystem. So the filesystem itself should be ok. Which folder are you trying to write to? Can you also give the output of "ls -la <the_folder>" ?

Comment: I added a picture to the bottom which is a picture of what I get when I do the requested command. Let me know if you need me to do anything else. :)

Comment: I just realized you are about to install VMware Tools. If you are doing that by the book, then the /mnt/cdrom gets automatically mounted by VMware and the most complicated thing you need to do is `mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom` if /mnt/cdrom is not already accessible.

Comment: Another stupid question. Does /mnt/cdrom already exist??

Comment: I know this is a late answer to the question @socken23 asked, but I just noticed it and it may help someone else in the same situation reading the question. The directory /mnt/cdrom does not necessarily have to exist. If it doesn't exist, you can just run the command "mkdir /mnt/cdrom" to create it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Although this is a relatively old question, the answer is still the same. You have a virtual machine (running on a physical host) and some sort of storage (either shared storage – a FC SAN, iSCSI storage, an NFS share – or local storage).

With virtualisation, many virtual machines try to access the same physical resources at the same time. Due to physical limitations (number of read/write operations – IOPS; throughput; latency) there might be a problem to satisfy all storage requests of all physical machines at the same time. What usually happens: you will be able to see "SCSI retries" and failed SCSI operations in the operating systems of your virtual machines. If you get too many errors/retries in a certain period of time, the kernel will set the mounted filesystems read-only in order to prevent damage to the filesystem.

To cut the long story short: Your physical storage is not "powerful" enough. There are too many processes (virtual machines) accessing the storage system at the same time, your virtual machines do not get the response from the storage fast enough, and the filesystem goes read-only.

There are not terribly many things you can do. The obvious solution is better/additional storage. You can also modify the parameters for SCSI timeouts in the Linux kernel. Details are described, e.g., in:

http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1009465

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/vmware-esx-server-scsi-timeout-for-linux-guest.html

However, this will only "postpone" your problems, because the kernel only gets more time before the filesystem will be set read-only. (I.e., you do not solve the cause of the problem.)

My experience (several years with VMware) is that this problem only exists with Linux kernels (we're using RHEL and SLES) and not with Windows servers. Also, this problem occurs on all sorts of storage – FC, iSCSI, local storage. For us, the most critical (and expensive) component in our virtual infrastructure is storage. (We're now using HP LeftHand with 1 Gbps iSCSI connections, and have not had any storage issues ever since. We chose LeftHand (over traditional FC-solutions) for its scalability.

Comment: Wow! Great answer. I completely forgot about this question. I have marked your answer as the accepted one. The datacenter I currently work with (which is a big VMWare partner) has upgraded their storage recently to a Hitachi Pod. We are actually adding another pod to the environment to help the load of IOPs because we started to run into additional issues with IOPs (pre emphasizing that we needed to upgraded or expand the SAN resources). SO in the past wee, we have increased our SAN resources again.

Comment: This is definitely what happened to me. I ran ffmpeg to build 2 videos of some 50 Gb and that was done in 2 min. in memory, but the disk ran for 10 min. straight (swamped!) Once done, all my VMs (4 at that time) were dead... I just had to reboot the VMs to fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

A likely explanation is that there is a hardware problem (partial disk failure), and that the kernel remounted the root filesystem as read-only as soon as it detected the problem, in order to minimize the problem. A more reliable¹ way to check current mount options is `cat /proc/mounts` (`grep ' / ' /proc/mounts` for the root filesystem, ignore a `rootfs / …` line which is an artefact of the boot process). You will presumably find that `rw,errors=remount-ro` has changed to `ro` (other options may be displayed in addition).

The kernel logs probably contain the message `Remounting filesystem read-only`, preceded by disk access errors. The logs normally live in `/var/log/kern.log`, however if this is on a now read-only filesystem the message will not show up there, though the preceding errors should. You can also see the latest few kernel errors with the `dmesg` command.

As an aside, under Ubuntu, the usual place for mount points (used by the desktop interface) is under `/media` (e.g. `/media/cdrom0`), though you can use `/mnt` or `/mnt/cdrom` if you like.

¹ 
<sub>`mount` reports from `/etc/mtab`. If the root filesystem is read-only, `/etc/mtab` can't be kept up-to-date.</sub>

Comment: The only thing about bad hardware is that this is a virtual machine, therefore it couldn't be a hardware issue as there are hundreds of virtual machines on the physical hosts and mine is the only one with an issue. I will check the kernel logs and try to put a screenshot of it in the question.

Comment: If you have a size limit on your virtual hard disk, and it's full, Ubuntu will fail to write, just as shown above.  You might check.

Comment: @David: The logs do show that Linux encountered a hardware problem, only the hardware is virtual. I find CarlF's hypothesis highly plausible.

Answer (score 3):

What happened was, there was a power failure in the data center recently. Since then, I haven't touched my server. Once our data center loses power, VSphere makes Ubuntu's file system read only until it is restarted. I would have tried restarting but I didn't want all of the monitoring to go crazy. I have silenced Nagios (monitoring service) and everything is working fine now that I have restarted the system. Thanks for all of the input. It is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Might be obvious, but are you "root" user when trying to do this?  /mnt is owned by root and only writable by root. You might also check to see if you had errors on boot.  Your output above says that / (and thus /mnt) should be remounted read only if boot process sees errors.  You can change this (ie remounting as r/w) with the mount command, but I wouldn't do this unless you're sure that whatever caused the error isn't serious.

Comment: I might not have been in a root by accident when I did that, but I think that the output it the same. The for sure root output is below the first output.

Answer (score 1):

When I looked at the output when running vagrant up, it appeared to be an issue on /dev/sda1:

Umount /dev/sda1:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda1
```

Check damaged partition:

```
fsck /dev/sda1
```

You’ll see some questions, you should answer yes to everything.

Thanks to [Jefferson Aboleda](https://www.jarboleda.me/articles/fixing-corrupted-partition-on-virtual-machine/) for this solution

Comment: This worked for me on ubuntu 18.04. I didn't need to unmount the problem disk. (In my case it was /dev/sda2). And I was able to run `fsck /dev/sda2` and after answering yes to all the issues, I rebooted, and the disk was now read/write.