# /tmp/ read-only

Tags: linux

When I'm trying delete some of the old eaccelerator files it gives me following errors

```
rm: cannot remove `/tmp/eaccelerator/7/2/eaccelerator-0502.02065984': Read-only file system
```

What can I do it fix it?

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2             226G  127G   88G  60% /
/dev/sdc1             227G  102G  114G  48% /disk1
/dev/sda1              99M   18M   77M  19% /boot
tmpfs                 4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sdb1             459G  182G  255G  42% /home4
/usr/tmpDSK           485M  325M  135M  71% /tmp
```

That's my output from the server.

Also what commands can I use to unmount and mount it? And should I do it while my web server is running?

Comment: Post the `$ mount` results here.

Comment: Maybe related to https://superuser.com/questions/207100/ubuntu-vm-read-only-file-system-fix

Answer (score 2):

Try with remount option:

```
mount -o remount,rw /tmp
```

Now you should be able to delete any file/directory inside /tmp

Answer (score 1):

Check that /tmp isn't mounted as a read only filesystem.

```
$ mount
```

unmount mount it, then re mount with rw option. Or if /tmp is just a ramdisk  (tmpfs) like it is on mine. umount than mount will clear the contents.